# Listen for all incoming traffic on port

Tags: python, http, traffic

With python, I have compiled the following script:

```
from socket import *

socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 80))
while True:
    data, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print addr[1]
```

It is supposed to receive all incoming traffic from port 80. However, if I load a webpage, it does not lot anything. Is there a problem with my script?

Comment: Could you perhaps tell on which OS you're on? I have a suspicion ...

Comment: HTTP uses stream sockets (TCP), not datagram sockets (UDP). And your code does't show traffic *from* port 80. It creates a server that responds to requests *to* port 80.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, when I change SOCK_DGRAM to SOCK_STREAM, it says I have more than one usage of port 80. Is this because programs like chrome already have port 80 bound?

Comment: It's because you're already running a webserver, and it is bound to port 80. Chrome connects to the **remote** port 80, it doesn't bind the **local** port 80.

Comment: If you want to sniff traffic on a port, use WireShark.

Answer (score 4):

If you truly want to listen to *all* incoming traffic on all interfaces, perhaps try to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1?

And as just stated, your socket pairing is a bit odd. This should get you started:

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 80))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    print s.accept()[1]
```

Comment: That would make sense, but, that doesn't seem to work either. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this, but the same problem arises, it says I have more than one usage of port 80. Is this because programs like chrome already have port 80 bound?

Comment: Unlikely it's chrome. But it sure sounds like another process is listening on port 80. Look out for any rogue python processes.

Comment: You are right in that sometimes rogue python processes cause this, as I have learned, but there seems to be nothing else open...

Comment: K, I'm closing in on terra incognita here as I haven't done any serious windows administration in years. But: `netstat -tp` should tell you which processes are listening on which tcp ports.

Comment: I have done that, but nothing is listed. In addition, if I do `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`, it says that the socket was accessed in a way that was forbidden by it's access permissions. However, I'm running as admin... Is anybody else having the same problem?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand I'm out. See if the system logs reveal anything interesting. Additionally, try to bind to a non-privileged port (that is any > 1023) to root out any other problems.

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be some misconceptions here, and wanted to make clear for future visitors. When you visit a website you don't send packets out of port 80, you send packets from a *random* port to the port 80 of a different machine. In this case you are expecting to have packets on your port 80 when you are visiting website: this can't happen. This would only apply if you are hosting a website or listening on that port.